# Inserting images into a JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using `HTTPservlet` to handle requests from a user

**this is the content of the doget method**

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Blog.jsp");
```

**Blog.jsp** file

```
<body>
   <h1><%= "Hello World!" %></h1>
   <br/>
   <img src="">
</body>
```

I have a image in my Oracle database that I want to upload it into that `img` element.

And to be more specific I don't want to upload it into a file in my project and than put that file path inside that `img` element

***is that possible?***

Comment: Did you consider making a separate servlet for the image file? That way you can point your image src to that servlet, and have it return the byte stream.

Comment: @Kraylog Yes, I thought about that, and it really helps me. The problem is that I did not find the correct code for that servlet i tried so many time, can you help me if you have the code please

Comment: You can use `src="data:image/png;base64, BASE64 ENCODED IMAGE HERE`